# Can't connect to multiple wifi networks

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, pi-1

I'm having trouble connecting to a network that isn't the first one in my `wpa_supplicant.conf` file (`NETWORK3`). I can connect to `NETWORK1` just fine, but it is a Wifi hotspot, so I would prefer to not use it. The problem is that it cannot connect either to `NETWORK2` or `NETWORK3` even if the other one isn't broadcasting. I am using the Wi-Pi USB Wifi dongle, so the interface is `wlx000f54020407`, not `wlan0`. I do not have a monitor, so I'm connecting to the pi through ssh. The pi is a model 1B running Raspbian version 9.

My `wpa_supplicant` file looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=CA

network={
    ssid="NETWORK1"
    psk="PASSWORD1"
    priority=10
}

network={
    ssid="NETWORK2"
    psk="PASSWORD2"
    priority=12
}

network={
    ssid="NETWORK3"
    psk="PASSWORD3"
    priority=5
}
```

My `interfaces` file:
If I put anything with `wlan0` in this file, the networking service doesn't start.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlx000f54020407
iface wlx000f54020407 inet dhcp
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Here's what happens when I turn off the hotspot (`NETWORK1`) for a minute - this is from `dmesg`:

```
[ 3379.870491] wlx000f54020407: deauthenticated from 3e:dc:bc:3c:0f:3a (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 3381.132294] wlx000f54020407: authenticate with 3e:dc:bc:3c:0f:3a
[ 3381.163746] wlx000f54020407: send auth to 3e:dc:bc:3c:0f:3a (try 1/3)
[ 3381.276358] wlx000f54020407: send auth to 3e:dc:bc:3c:0f:3a (try 2/3)
[ 3381.386376] wlx000f54020407: send auth to 3e:dc:bc:3c:0f:3a (try 3/3)
[ 3381.506361] wlx000f54020407: authentication with 3e:dc:bc:3c:0f:3a timed out
[ 3456.248189] wlx000f54020407: authenticate with 3e:dc:bc:3c:0f:3a
[ 3456.280182] wlx000f54020407: send auth to 3e:dc:bc:3c:0f:3a (try 1/3)
[ 3456.304500] wlx000f54020407: authenticated
[ 3456.314494] wlx000f54020407: associate with 3e:dc:bc:3c:0f:3a (try 1/3)
[ 3456.319038] wlx000f54020407: RX AssocResp from 3e:dc:bc:3c:0f:3a (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3456.319064] wlx000f54020407: invalid AID value 0x1; bits 15:14 not set
[ 3456.332099] wlx000f54020407: associated
```

Every network shows up when I do `iwlist wlx000f54020407 scan` as root. Here's the information for `NETWORK1`:

```
Cell 02 - Address: 3E:DC:BC:3C:0F:3A
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETWORK1"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000000d200ed3e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00036E6574
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A2D0117FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B001300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD050016328000
                    IE: Unknown: DD080050F21102000000
```

and `NETWORK3`:

```
Cell 04 - Address: 90:50:CA:B9:6D:F8
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETWORK3"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000026788b22ad
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000657616E206C69
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD011BFFFFFF00000000000000000001000000000406E6470D00
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD9E0050F204104A00011010440001021057000101103B00010310470010B5862471C47554CEB60835B1D058B06B10210017486974726F6E20546563686E6F6C6F67792C20496E632E102300044150787810240008415078782D7878781042001253657269616C204E756D62657220486572651054000800060050F204000110110008486974726F6E4150100800022008103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

I've tried using an empty `interfaces.conf`, and various different configurations of `wpa_supplicant.conf`. I don't know what else to try, so help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have selected NETWORK2 as your highest priority, NETWORK1 as next, so it is hardly surprising it uses these!

Your interfaces file is inconsistent, and the use of dhcp disables the default Raspbian network manager - you are lucky it works at all.

You have obviously made other changes to the default Raspbian setup - we can only guess what and why.

Comment: The issue that I'm having is that even if `NETWORK2` and `NETWORK1` are not broadcasting, it still doesn't connect to `NETWORK3`. It just doesn't connect to anything at that point. Any changes that I've made are for the purpose of trying to connect to `NETWORK3`.