# Unable to connect to wifi - ifup service failed

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, pi-1

I'm using a raspberry pi model 1B with a dongle and I can't connect it to wifi. It was working ([mostly](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98230/cant-connect-to-multiple-wifi-networks)) a few weeks ago, but now the wifi doesn't work at all. The log shows something about the ifup service not starting up, so I assume that is the problem. the full log is here: [pastebin log](https://pastebin.com/6nkVtQwr) Should I just re-flash Raspbian? I don't want to do that because I would have to set it up headless.

I've checked that the wpa_supplicant configuration is correct, and I haven't changed any settings since it was working.

Comment: What operating system do you use? With *Raspbian Stretch* `ifupdown` isn't used anymore.

Comment: Raspbian version 9